# iOS: How use Twitter Kit to get current trending topics

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-fabric

I've installed Fabric & Twitter Kit in my iOS app and was wondering what steps i need to take to grab the current top trends from Twitter.

I've looked around and there is documentation on this, I've got an endpoint: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json?id=1, however, this doesn't seem to be working.

Here's my code which is after a user has signed in:

```
 TWTRLogInButton *logInButton = [TWTRLogInButton buttonWithLogInCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {

    if (session) {
        NSLog(@"%@ logged in", [session userName]);
        [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:[session userName] forKey:@"twitterLink"];
        [[PFUser currentUser]saveInBackground];

        //try and get the trending topics

        NSURL *topicsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json?id=1"];

        NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:topicsURL];

        if (jsonData == nil) {
            //no internet / no data
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"TOPICS DATA %@", jsonData);
        }
    }
```

I believe this issue is to do with authenticating the user, does Twitter kit authenticate the user for api calls just by signing them in?